# How to PUT a binary file with javascript/jQuery to webdav?

Tags: ajax, encoding, request, put, webdav

How can I PUT a binary file, say an image with an HTTP PUT request to webdav? I already tried base64 encoding, but the file is broken.

```
$.ajax({
   url: url + file,
   data:base64content,
   type: 'PUT',
   crossDomain: true,
   headers:{'content-type':'image/png'},
   xhrFields:{withCredentials: true}
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a solution on this site:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Sending_and_Receiving_Binary_Data

```
var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
oReq.open("POST", url, true);
oReq.onload = function (oEvent) {
  // Uploaded.
};

var blob = new Blob(['abc123'], {type: 'text/plain'});

oReq.send(blob);
```